# How can I bypass the mixed content error (http/https)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests, cucumberjs

I am getting the below error when I was trying to approve a document in a webpage

```
Mixed Content: The page at \'https://example.com\' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource \'http://insecure-page.com:9870/xyz\'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.'
```

It is because my test is trying to load a non secure page over a secured page . Could someone help to bypass this error so I can continue with the rest of the steps in my automation testing script . I am using Protractor-cucumber-javascript framework

Comment: The above solution is not working

Comment: I have tried  the following  `chrome_single: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    acceptInsecureCerts : true,
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        'window-size=1600,1024',
        'disable-infobars',
        'allow-running-insecure-content',
        'allow-insecure-localhost'
      ]
    }`

Comment: You need to change to `https` and use self-signed certificate, then solution from link

Comment: I can't change it because it is a link coming from another integrated system

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I tried this approach

```
<iframe [src]="your-https-original-domain?URL=your-http-url" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
```

Hope this would help.

Refer: https://www.brokenbrowser.com/loading-insecure-content-in-secure-pages/